# Cannot access contents of wwwroot folder in Google App Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a fairly standard .net core MVC application built on Visual Studio for Mac.  I have published may simalar projects to Azure App Services.

I'm now trying to publish this MVC app to Google App Engine.  It publishes and runs, but none of the static content from the wwwroot folder is accessible from the browser - all file paths return 404.

I've confirmed the files are being copied to the server.  Via SSH I run `sudo docker exec -it gaeapp /bin/bash`

In the directory I land in, I see the following:

```
DnsClient.dll                              
Dockerfile                                 
... (project dlls)
app.yaml
appsettings.json
bundleconfig.json
publish
runtimes
source-context.json
web.config
```

In the publish directory I see:

```
DnsClient.dll
... (project dlls)
app.yaml
appsettings.json
bundleconfig.json
runtimes
web.config
wwwroot
```

wwwroot contains all the files I expect.  I've tried copying files out of wwwroot to various levels of the tree, but still cannot access the files.

Here's my app.yaml in case that helps:

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment. 
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
env_variables:
  # The __ in My__Greeting will be translated to a : by ASP.NET.
  My__Greeting: Hello AppEngine!root@c2d2b26894e2:/app#
```

Any ideas how I might fix this?

**More Info**

In case there was an issue with my project, I created a new MVC project from the VS template and published this.  Same issue, as shown in the screenshot below.  Tried with default template, plus added `app.UseDefaultFiles();` as suggested in an answer.

[image: Screenshot of page with resources 404ing]

So, I assume the issue is in Google or the deployment...

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow the an app engine flexible for dotnet to serve static files you have to allow it by using:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

On your main file. This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/serving-static-files#example_of_serving_static_files_with_your_app).

I don't recommend it to do it if you're generating your files dynamically and putting them on the `wwwroot` folder, since one instance could have the files generated, but if another one wakes up it could be possible that the file isn't found there. For that kind of situation I suggest to use [`Cloud Storage`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/serving-static-files#example_of_serving_from_a_bucket) as an alternative to a CDN

Comment: Thank you for that; I had already seen this (although omitted to mention).  My app already had `UseStaticFiles` - Sadly adding `UseDefaultFiles` didn't fix my issue

Comment: How are you trying to access to your files? I mean what's the approximate URL that you're using?

Comment: Directly at the expected Url; but also as seen in the browser network console; example Url: `https://....appspot.com/css/site.min.css`

Comment: I had `UseStaticFiles()` in program.cs. Adding `UseDefaultFiles()` made no difference!